# Centered background gets cropped in html

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem trying to center a background horizontally in the following situation:

- background is large and has to be centered horizontally
- the page has a minimum width of 960px and there has to be a scrollbar on smaller screens

So i've decided to do this (pseudocode):

```
<bg-div> # this will contain the background image with "center center no-repeat" option
    <content-div> # this will be 960px margin 0 auto
    </content-div>
</bg-div>
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/CtMRt/4/

The problem: The background should stop centering itself on smaller than 960px resolutions, but instead a white gap appears on the right side of the page and the background keeps centering itself. How would i solve something like this?

Thanks for your thoughts

Comment: <del>Replace `center center` with `left center`</del>

Comment: @NabilKadimi OP is trying to horizontally center the image..

Comment: @NabilKadimi the background NEEDS to be horizontally centered. Replacing with left center will align it to the left of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css media queries: ([working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CtMRt/5/))

```
@media screen and (max-width:960px){
   bg-div{background:url(..) left center;}
}
```

Also, you didn't set `min-width:900px;` to the container.. try using: ([another working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CtMRt/7/))

`.sec { height: 90px; min-width:900px; }`

Comment: Yes, i know that. Not a solution in my case though. This seems like something that should be simple to fix without resorting to such measures.

Comment: @Marius You didn't set `min-width:900px` to the outer div.. this should also fix your problem.. adding to answer..

Comment: Figures ... told you it was simple. Thank you. Will IE7 support this though?